# How to set up Microsoft Edge Chromium in kiosk mode with silent printing?

Tags: windows, powershell, printing, microsoft-edge, kiosk-mode

I am trying to start Microsoft Edge *with parameters* in Kiosk mode via Assigned Access. A client of mine has requested that users should only be allowed to browse one specific website (in this case, users can print name tags at a reception stand).

[image]

Now, we can start the Edge browser without problems via Assigned Access and have it launch the specific website in full screen but when it comes to printing, a print dialogue will always appear. We want silent printing to avoid the hassle for the users. Fortunately Edge has a command line (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-configure-kiosk-mode) where you can specify this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --kiosk https://www.example.org/ --kiosk-printing
```

However, this only works on when you create a shortcut to Edge on e.g. the Desktop and then launch manually - not when you start it via Assigned Access / Kiosk mode.

Show how do we add needed parameter `--kiosk-printing` to Kiosk mode?

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

**1) I have thought about using PowerShell:**

You can use PowerShell to configured Assigned Access / Kiosk mode.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/assignedaccess/set-assignedaccess?view=windowsserver2019-ps

```
PS C:\> Set-AssignedAccess -UserName MyKioskUser -AppName "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe --kiosk https://www.example.org/ --kiosk-printing"
```

But that just gives an error:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-AssignedAccess -UserName MyKioskUser
-AppName "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe --kiosk https://www.example.org/ --kiosk-printing" Application was not found.  Enter either a valid AppName or AUMID At C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\AssignedAccess\AssignedAccess.psm1:288 char:17
+                 throw $SCStringTable.ErrorAppNotFound
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Application was...ppName or AUMID:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Application was not found.  Enter either a valid AppName or AUMID
```

**2) Group Policy?**

Group Policy could perhaps be a way to enforce settings for an application like Microsoft Edge but I do not know how to configure that. Any feedback welcome.

**3) Maybe edge://policy would work?**

Edge has a lot of different policies/settings you can configure according to this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/microsoft-edge-policies#printing but there are no policy for silent printing.

**4) Is it possible to run a bat file instead?**

If Kiosk mode would allow for a custom app to run like a .bat file I could simply call that file and my problems would be solved. However, it seems you cannot even run a .bat file via Kiosk mode (correct me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found solution and it works in Assigned Access KIOSK same as in edge shortcut.

You need to run -> regedit

\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\AssignedAccessConfiguration\Profiles{"YourKioskProfile"}\AllowedApps\App0

and there you can find REG_SZ registry "Arguments" with all parameters.

You need to add there --kiosk-printing parameter and it will work.

Comment: works on windows 10 64 bit edge 94, thank you!

Comment: Why is this the only place on the internet where this is documented?? 

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to assign parameter `--kiosk-printing` via assigned access. Edge in kiosk mode is still in preview version, I suggest that you can raise feature request about Edge kiosk mode silent printing and provide your feedback about this issue by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge.