# launch edge in kiosk mode from batch or powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'll take a batch or powershell solution, but I need to launch Edge to a specific url in kiosk mode and not having much luck.  The following sees the kiosk parameter as part of the url string. This method of launching the app doesn't appear to accept parameters

```
start "" "shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" --Kiosk http://website.com
```

In powershell but it keeps telling me the application was not found, enter a valid appname or AUMID. But that is the correct aumid and its recognized by the batch file.

```
set-assignedAccess -UserName "kiosk" -AppName "Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge --kiosk http://website.com"
```

Though similar this is not a duplicate of [How to set up Microsoft Edge Chromium in kiosk mode with silent printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68322730/how-to-set-up-microsoft-edge-chromium-in-kiosk-mode-with-silent-printing)
They reference edge from program files and mine is not located there. Above has been the only way I've been able to reference it successfully from batch.

Comment: Why are you not using ```"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"```?

Comment: As I said above, edge is not located there. Frankly I don't know where windows stores the  actual file but its not in program files.

Comment: Okay then, what is the result from the following command `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\msedge.exe"`, `[ENTER]`ed at the Command Prompt?

Comment: Unable to find registry key or value.  I looked manually in App Paths, there is no edge listed there.

Comment: _(I'm rather suprised the Microsoft Edge is not a default, and protected built-in application)_. Could you please tell us which version(s) of Windows and PowerShell this is for? Normally you'd open a UWP app as an argument to explorer.exe, e.g. ```start "" "explorer.exe" "shell:…"```. I'm assuming when trying that, however, that command line arguments do not work; is that the case?

Comment: Windows 10. Seems like no matter what method I use I can't get anything to recognize --kiosk argument.   This is something we're going to push out to a lot of systems so I need a way that's going find edge consistently.  I believe on some systems it is indeed found in program files.

Comment: I just borrowed a Windows 10 PC, for one minute, opened a Command Prompt and pasted in ```start "" "shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" --Kiosk http://website.com```, as you had used. `http://website.com` appeared in a new tab in their already open Edge Browser. So clearly the website parameter is working. Are you reporting that it is, or isn't working for you, and perhaps that it's simply ignoring the `--kiosk` option.

Comment: it sees the website parameter, the problem is it thinks --kiosk is part of the address

Comment: Obviously in the very limited test I performed, the website opened as expected, i.e. without `--kiosk` being prepended in the address bar, _(perhaps auto-removed)_, or affecting the intended URI.

Comment: Someone has suggested that my version of edge is pre-chromium on the pc I'm testing with and thus it may not have the kiosk option.

Comment: Menu > Help and feedback > About Microsoft Edge should give you the information you need. Also you may require a minimum build number for Windows 10 _(`explorer.exe ms-settings:about`)_. What are yours?

Comment: My build is 1709.  My version of edge is unknown as there is no "about" option.  I tried from another computer and the command above works as expected. So the problem is folks giving me test equipment that doesn't match production....

Comment: Regardless that you appear to be using an obviously outdated Microsoft Edge version, your Operating System is over five and a half years out of date too, and its service status expired two and a third years ago.